# Intercept dict __getitem__ method call when it's passed to update method of another dict

Tags: python, dictionary

As you know, python allows us simply override `dict.__getitem__` method so we can do something different in there when someone tries to retrieve any value from it.

I want to do some code when one `MyDict(dict)` class instance is passed to update method of another python dict instance. See below:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print "Doing some stuff here"
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)

d1 = MyDict({'1': 1, '2': 2})
d2 = {}
# I want to have d1.__getitem__ called, but it does not work :-(
d2.update(d1)
```

Comment: Interesting; while ``help(d2.update)`` does suggest that it iterates over the passed collections and perform assignments for each key found, it seems that the internal implementation actually bypasses ``__getitem__``, likely for performance reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to subclass `MyDict` from `object` and create `.keys()` method for it. See below:

```
class MyDict(object):
    def __init__(self, items=()):
        self._dict = dict(items)

    def keys(self):
        return self._dict.keys()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print "Doing some stuff for item:", item
        return self._dict[item]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self._dict[item] = value

    # You can add some more dict methods

d1 = MyDict({'1': 1, '2': 2})
d2 = {}
# Now you will see some stuff executed for each
# value extracted from d1 while updating d2
d2.update(d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`collections.Mapping`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping) [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) (or [`collections.MutableMapping`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping), if this is read-write).

```
import collections

class MyDict(collections.Mapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.data

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print 'Doing some stuff here'
        return self.data[key]
```

Comment: It seems to me that `collections.Mapping` is not available in Python 2.5.4 version.

Comment: @astronaut Correct, these classes were added to Python 2.6 and 3.0.